# Django - Messages functionality not working in Class based view

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-messages

Unable to display messages in class based view. In another app's views.py, it is working fine where I used function based view.

views.py:

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
        model = Post
        success_url = '/user-profile/'
        success_message = "Your post has been deleted sucessfully!"
    
        def test_func(self):
            post = self.get_object()
            if self.request.user == post.author:
                return True
            return False
```

urls.py:

```
path('user-profile/', user_views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
```

html:

```
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeleteView` does not subclass `FormView` so `SuccessMessageMixin` will not do anything. You will have to add the message yourself, overriding the `delete` method seems like a good place

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    messages.success(self.request, 'Your post has been deleted sucessfully!')
    return response
```